# How to calculate common-mode filter?

Tags: filter, emc

I want to design a common-mode filter. I've done a lot of research on the internet but couldn't find a formula for it.

I have the common choke material that I should use in my circuit, but I don't know how to determine the values of the capacitances that I need to connect to the filter. Can you advise me on this matter? Why is there no formula or program for the calculation of the common-mode filter design?

Comment: Sorry but there is no context to buid on. Do you want a common mode filter for mains voltage, or for 1 Gbps Ethernet, or for 20 Gbps USB?

Comment: Please add that information to the question, along with other specifications you have, such as voltages, currents, frequencies you want to remove or leave, and how much attenuation at some frequencies are necessary.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against?  Conducted emissions (CE), or conducted susceptibility (CS).  If it's the former, you need to know 1) what your CE requirements are and 2) what you expect your equipment to put out, common mode wise, on the inputs.  Then you just design your filter to provide the needed attenuation.

Comment: And a lot depends of what the dynamics of your load looks like.  In the radar discipline, a large part of the input filter design is driven by the high power/current pulses that occur at the PRF.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas signal filters have well defined impedances, EMI filters do not.  The components used are also much less ideal (CMCs have resistance, capacitance and other higher order characteristics that are all relevant at EMI frequencies).  They also tend to be large, so, are sensitive to layout, even at the relatively low frequencies involved (10s MHz).

Basically, you make do with what kinds of things you have available, and empirical testing tends to be more effective than simulation.

Simulations are possible, but it requires much greater detail than is usually  available.  For example, it is not sufficient to plug in some coupled inductors in LTSpice and call that a transformer model; self and inter-winding capacitances, leakage, and higher order characteristics, are all part of the equivalent EMI circuit.  In the extreme, model extraction of the transformer, and even PCB and enclosure, may be required.  Needless to say, these are not data you will have available if the converter in question is a commercial module.

Answer (score 2):

To size a common-mode filter, you first need an EMI signature showing how much attenuation is needed from your filter to pass the specs with margins. To obtain the signature, you must separate differential-mode from common-mode noise. This is described in many application notes and the old [AN-15](https://emcfastpass.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/an15.pdf) from Power Integrations contains a lot of useful data as well as this [AN](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/separating-common-mode-and-differential-mode-emissions-in-conducted-emissions-testing.html) from Analog Devices.

Assume the extracted common-mode signature shows a peak of 50 dBµV at 10 MHz but you would like to attenuate it by 30 dB so that it becomes 20 dBµV after the filter. You should then determine a filter which is going to attenuate by 30 dB a 10-MHz signal. The attenuation depends on the cutoff frequency and obeys the below expression for a 2nd-order filter:

[image]

You will then identify the inductive components specifically sized to handle the operating current which, once associated to the selected capacitor will lead to the attenuation you want. There are plenty of documents such as this [AN](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slyp757/slyp757.pdf?ts=1667407983554&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) from TI or this [one](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/doc191_CMFiltDesign.pdf) from Coilcraft which will help you understand how to design this type of filter.

As a side note, you have to understand the interaction between a front-end EMI filter and a dc-dc converter. It is important to realize the potential issues when associating the two. My [APEC 2017](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) seminar should be a good introduction to the underlying theory and how to prevent oscillation mechanisms.